# Rails: Garble data as it leaves the database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Basically, I'm looking for a way to inject code before queries are executed against certain tables. For example, if I query against the users table (ignore the joins/or complex statement possibilities) I want to garble the output so that you can still get *something* back but it won't be readable.

The solution needs to be something that doesn't modify the actual data in the database. I'm basically looking to give customers a way to see the layouts and such without giving them the actual data in the database.

Second example: I'm User A. I go to a page and I see a mailing label and the label says:

Foo Jones
123 Foo Street
SF CA 93218

This is the actual information in the database. Now, User B visits that same page but instead of seeing the above they see:

asdfasdf adsfasdfasdf
123 Foo Street
SF CA 93218

In the above something could be called that would dump out the name but show the address block. It would, in theory be abstracted away from the views/controller code and possibly on the model.

Help? Thoughts? Is this a pipe dream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just do it in the view - rather than at ActiveRecord data querying layer.

My first thought is to implement a `Obfuscator` class like `UserObfuscator` - which is basically a decorator.

Proof of concept:

```
class UserObfuscator
  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
    self
  end

  def id
    @user.id
  end

  def first_name
    SecureRandom.hex(6)
  end

  def last_name
    SecureRandom.hex(6)
  end

  # .. implement as many of these methods as you need.

end
```

Then in your view:

```
<%- obfuscator = UserObfuscator.new(@user) %>
Hello, <%= obfuscator.first_name %>
```

You could clean up the view a little bit and move this method to either a helper or the model itself by:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def obfuscator
    @_obfuscator ||= UserObfuscator.new(self)
  end
end
```

Then in your view:

```
Hello, <%= @user.obfuscator.first_name %>
```

But its pretty much 6 or half a dozen.

Comment: Yeah, a co-worker suggested something similar which essentially becomes a blacklist kind of solution. Pick a bunch of fields you think will have PII and then scramble them.